# Deveria haver um espaço entre a barra e o substantivo?

Tags: sinais-gráficos

Estava escrevendo um texto e finalizando digitei:

> Diretor/CEO

Mas não me parece a maneira correta. Qual dessas é correta?

> Diretor/CEO

ou

> Diretor **/** CEO

ou

> Diretor/ CEO

ou

> Diretor /CEO

Answer (score 1):

Se neste sítio [Pequeno Livro de Dicas de Diagramação de Lucas Luz](https://issuu.com/lucasluz9/docs/pequeno_livro_de_dicas_de_diagrama_) dermos uma busca por "Espaço antes da barra", encontraremos o exemplo "Exemplo/Livro" sem espaço. Em rigor, os livros nunca colocam espaço(s) nem antes nem depois duma barra transversal ou oblíqua.

"f) a barra transversal é usada entre números e datas de fascículos não
seqüenciais (ex: 7/9, 1979/1981);"¹
Fonte: http://biblioteca.fecap.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Manual-ABNT_-regras-gerais-de-estilo-e-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-trabalhos-acad%C3%AAmicos.pdf

Ver também o Ciberdúvidas:
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/espaco-antes-e-depois-da-barra/22261

---

¹ Observar que não há espaço(s) entre um número e outro ou entre uma data e outra. *Ipso facto*, não devemos colocar espaço(s) nem antes nem depois da barra. Portanto, "**Diretor/CEO**".